# How to bounce the player away after attack by enemies?

Tags: unity, 2d

I creating a 2d platform game. I would like to bounce the player away after hit by the enemy, so the user get another feedback beside the sound effect.

How can I achieve my wish?

Use the following code for my enemy attack:

```
public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 25;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.

    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
    GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.

    bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
    float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.


    void Awake () {
        // Setting up the references.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
        //enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other) {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player) {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
        }

    }


    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) {
        // If the exiting collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player) {
            // ... the player is no longer in range.
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }


    void Update () {
        // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range and this enemy is alive...
        if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange) {
            // ... attack.
            Attack ();
        }

        // If the player has zero or less health...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0) {
            // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
            anim.SetTrigger ("PlayerDead");
        }

    }


    void Attack () {
        // Reset the timer.
        timer = 0f;

        // If the player has health to lose...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0) {
            // ... damage the player.
            playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
        }
    }
```

The enemies do have a `box collider 2D`, and the script you can see above.
Player has also a box and circle `collider 2d`, a `rigid body2D` and a player health script:

```
public int startingHealth = 100;                            // The amount of health the player starts the game with.
    public int currentHealth;                                   // The current health the player has.
    public Slider healthSlider;                                 // Reference to the UI's health bar.
    public Image damageImage;                                   // Reference to an image to flash on the screen on being hurt.
    public AudioClip hurtClip;
    private AudioSource source;
    public float flashSpeed = 5f;                               // The speed the damageImage will fade at.
    public Color flashColour = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);     // The colour the damageImage is set to, to flash.

    public float internalStrength = 1000;
    public int externalStrength = 1000;


    Animator anim;                                              // Reference to the Animator component.
    PlayerMovement playerMovement;                              // Reference to the player's movement.

    bool isDead;                                                // Whether the player is dead.
    bool damaged;                                               // True when the player gets damaged.


    void Awake () {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        source = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        playerMovement = GetComponent <PlayerMovement> ();

        // Set the initial health of the player.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }


    void Update () {
        //internalStrength -= Time.deltaTime;
        //externalStrength = Mathf.RoundToInt(internalStrength) + Random.Range(-100, 100);

        // If the player has just been damaged...
        if(damaged) {
            // ... set the colour of the damageImage to the flash colour.
            damageImage.color = flashColour;


        }
        // Otherwise...
        else {
            // ... transition the colour back to clear.
            damageImage.color = Color.Lerp (damageImage.color, Color.clear, flashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Reset the damaged flag.
        damaged = false;


    }


    public void TakeDamage (int amount) {
        // Set the damaged flag so the screen will flash.
        damaged = true;

        // Reduce the current health by the damage amount.
        currentHealth -= amount;

        // Set the health bar's value to the current health.
        healthSlider.value = currentHealth;

        // Play the hurt sound effect.
        source.PlayOneShot (hurtClip);

        // If the player has lost all it's health and the death flag hasn't been set yet...
        if(currentHealth <= 0 && !isDead) {
            // ... it should die.
            Death ();
        }
    }


    void Death () {
        // Set the death flag so this function won't be called again.
        isDead = true;

        // Tell the animator that the player is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("Die");

        // Set the audiosource to play the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt sound from playing).


        // Turn off the movement and shooting scripts.
        playerMovement.enabled = false;
    }
```

If there is something unclear or whatever, ask me!
Look out for some advice.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your problems that you've run into implementing this? Is there a reason you can't just apply a force to the player on collision with enemies? Also that's a lot of code your pasting into here - health system, variables... try trimming it down to just what's important.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Rigidbody2D.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) to the palyer rigidbody, using force mode :  [Impulse](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode2D.html) ("This mode is useful for applying forces that happen instantly, such as forces from explosions or collisions").

Put tha addforce into your TakeDamage()

Answer (score 0):

You could use RigidBody2D.AddForce(Vector3) to make knockback or you could have and animation of the player being bounced.